# All inclusive tool to convert different types of documents to pdf

Tags: java, pdf, command-line, document, file-conversion

I've been looking around the web for a tool I can use with Java. Whether it be a Java API or a command-line interface I can create a Java wrapper around to give me the ability to convert multiple types of documents to a PDF.

Here is the list of documents I need to be able to convert to PDF:

- images (.tiff, .jpeg, .png, .bmp, .gif)
- MS WORD (.doc, .docx)
- text files (.txt, .rtf)

Here are some notes on what I have found so far around the web related to pdf conversion

JODConverter - http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter
    looks to convert a lot of different types of formats to PDF
    Is no longer actively developed
    FREE

iText will not work - http://itextpdf.com/itext.php/
    "iText can convert an XML or an XHTML/CSS file to PDF (using XML Worker). Converting documents from one format to another is outside the scope of iText. And no: iText does not convert Word documents to PDF!"

GhostScript - http://www.ghostscript.com/
    Converts postscript to pdf
    need to find software which would convert file formats to ps first
    maybe not the best solution
    FREE

Qoppa Software - http://www.qoppa.com/solutions/javapdf.html
    jPDFImages - creates pdfs from jpg, tif and png images
    jWordConvert - converts word documents to PDF (doc, docx)
    Costs money

imagemagick - http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php
    converts one image to a pdf at a time
    would need to be used with a batch script to combine all pdfs into one
    doesn't do anything other than images.
    FREE

If any of the information about these products is incorrect, any corrections would be appreciated.

Is there a solution out there which is still actively supported which would do all of these conversions in one piece of software?

I feel like this is a common problem people come across and there has to be a better solution than combining several third party products together. It can be open source or require a license and money.

Comment: If you don't mind a commercial product then have a look at http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-Services/summary.aspx DISCLAIMER, I worked on this product. Having said that, it works great with Java, .NET, C#, SharePoint, Documentum, JRuby and many other webservices capable environments.

Comment: I am considering Aspose PDF (www.aspose.com) but I can't understand if it can also convert Word files. It can only manipulate PDF files, so I need a component to decode Word

Comment: Any Updates for this question ?